# Stripe : Form data is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, strip

The problem is quite clear, I am posting the strip element form, I am posting it as `POST` request, The result is `null`, I am getting the request output and its `null`.

Js code :

```
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
$("#submitNewCard").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            let errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
            let stripToken = result.token;
            let formData = new FormData(form);
            formData.append('stripe_key', JSON.stringify(stripToken));
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "/add/new/card",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#cover').show();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#cover').hide();
                    return true;
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    $('#cover').hide();
                    toastr.error(error.responseJSON.message);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Html code form :

```
<form method="post" id="payment-form">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="HelloHidden" value="hidden value">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
    </div>
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div><br/>
  <button type="button" id="submitNewCard" class="btn btn-primary">Add Card</button>
</form>
```

What am i missing ? Why the `formData` is null.

Comment: did you try with: formData = $('#payment-form').serialize(); ?

Comment: @Maky Yeah, That gives me the values, But the `stripToken` is not appending to it

Comment: Ok if you do a dd whatis the response?